# Connection and bandwidth problems with wireless AC tri-band router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, 802.11ac

I recently bought a new router (Netgear Nighthawk R8000 AC3200) to use in tandem with my modem and has DD-WRT installed on it since the stock firmware limited my connection to 30 mbps. However, the problem is that I'm only getting 300 mbps wireless connections to the router. It is a tri-band router in which I'm utilizing two 5GHz 80MHz-wide radios and a 2.4 GHz 40MHz-wide radio. The two 5GHz radios are on different channel levels (36 and 161). I live in a small apartment that shares the spectrum with 7 other people's networks. I've been trying to figure out how to combine my two 5GHz radios into using the same SSID but doing so prevents me from connecting to the wireless network.

Comment: Your not going to be able to combine the two radios into a single ssid but that also wouldn't solve your bandwidth problems even if you did

Comment: @Ramhound The router has a max ac bandwidth of 1300mbps and the stock firmware has a feature called Smart Connect which "combines" the two 5Ghz radios into a single SSID. Source: http://bit.ly/2nhYN8A

Comment: Sounds like your client devices are to blame.... is every song client using 802.11ac.  I know about the router, and it doesn't literally combine them, it handles the transfer between two hidden ssids and you connect to a virtual ssid but that doesn't double your bandwidth or anything like that.

Comment: An 802.11 link between a client and an AP (wireless router) is only as fast as the subset of 802.11 technologies and options that both the client and the AP support. You need to give us detailed data about the 802.11 capabilities of your client. If your client only supports 2-stream 802.11n with 40MHz wide channels, then it can never do better than a 300Mbps PHY rate even when talking to an AP that supports 1300 Mbps AC. You need a 1300 Mbps AC client to do 1300 Mbps AC with a 1300Mbps AC access point.